# textviews cut off inside nesteadscrollview

Tags: android, xml

I have Coordinatorlayout which contain collaping section and nestedscrollview section so this is the layout code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".ScheduleDetailsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_url"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:minHeight="300dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom|end"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingEnd="12dp"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:paddingRight="12dp"
                android:paddingStart="12dp"
                android:paddingTop="18dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/buttons_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
                        style="@style/DetailsButton"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@id/shareButton"
                        android:text="@string/favorite" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/shareButton"
                        style="@style/DetailsButton"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:nextFocusUp="@id/saveButton"
                        android:text="@string/share" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/score" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/score_details"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/synopsis" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/synopsis_details"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

the problem is with nestedscrollview content the textviews when it have long text it's just reached to bottom screen and cut off the text somtime 1 line and sometime 2 or 3 and so on
I search a lot and implement relative layout and layout_gravity=fill but nothing work

this is the screen of layout when the content is short:

[image]

and this is screen when the content is long:

[image]

how fix thisand make all texts appear

Answer (score 0):

First, try to replace `<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>` scroll view from

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

if it does not work for u try below steps.

Try it by removing `<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>` as a parent of layout. Then wrap all the  using  `<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>`

as an example

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:padding="10dp">

      <TextView/>

      </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried it already but I add the framelayout because I saw this suggestion in one of stackoverflow questions but it didn't solve the problem @Lucefer

Comment: can you explain your answer more cuz I didn't understand it @Lucefer

Comment: U need to wrap all text view by using <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView> then it will added scroll for particular text view. Most probably it will not working because of you try to add NestedScrollView for full layout. Did you try this ?

Comment: I think your code will work when you remove frame layout and you add scrollView instead of nestedScrollView. @GNDevs I updated my answer again. You can try it now